# Matching Class list by value

Tags: java, android

I have 2 lists of class:

```
List<Person> ls1
List<Person> ls2
```

The Class person:

```
public class Person {
   String name;
   String id;
}
```

The ls1 have the person class with names and ls2 have names and iD.
What I need to do is go match list by name and then copy IDs from ls2 to ls1.

What is the most efficient way to do so besides building for loops for each person in ls1 and find it in ls2. How can I match them more quickly?

Comment: doesn't `ls1.contains(ls2.get(objectxyz));` work?

Comment: @XtremeBaumer probably not, why should it?

Comment: You probably can create temporary index, i.e. `HashMap<String, String>` with names and ids. In this case you will be able to reduce big-O from `O^2` to `~O`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Build a map using list2 and traverse through list1 and check if exists in map, then copy data. Here is the solution in Java 8

```
    final Map<String, Person> personByName = lis2.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(Person::getName, Function.identity()));
    lis1.forEach(person -> {
        final Person personFromMap= personByName.get(person.getName());
        if(Objects.nonNull(personFromMap)){
            //copy id, assuming a setId/getId method exist
            person.setId(personFromMap.getId());
        }
    });
```

Comment: `a->a` is a lot more terse than `Function.identity()`

Answer (score 0):

You could transform `ls2` into a map `name` to `id` and then loop through `ls1`, setting the `id`s from the map.

Answer (score 0):

I will do it this way

```
ls2.stream().filter(person ->
        person.getId()==YOURID).
        peek(person -> ls1.add(person))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```